# Issue using counters in datagridview c#

Tags: c#, wpf, datagridview

I have datagridview table. Whenever a user selects row and click 'Update Counter' button, counter value changes to 1 at top corner of window.

Now if a user selects the same row, the counter is updated incrementally which I don't want. I don't want counter to update on same row selection.

My code -

```
Int32 selectedRowCount = dataGridView1.Rows.GetRowCount(DataGridViewElementStates.Selected);                       

for (int i = 0; i < selectedRowCount; i++)
{                 
  // need to insert condition so that counter is not updated when same row is selected again.
 Counter.Text = Convert.ToString(i + 1);
                    }
}
```

I new to C# development, please provide changes.

Comment: Instead of all this, can't you just do `Counter.Text = Convert.ToString((dataGridView1.SelectedItems).Count)`

Comment: I have a button which when I click updates the counter. The logic should be that the counter should not be updates if the same row is selected by the user. Should I have to create a new db to check uniqueness of the row selected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, I created a SQL table storing all values from selected row. If selected row value is something already there in the table, the counter doesn't get updated while the counter gets updated when unique row is selected.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the rest of the code, or really understanding what you are doing (is this list going to change, what is the counter, can you identify the selected row easily?), all I can really suggest is maintaining a list of selected rows and checking that before updating the counter.

For example, in the for each:

```
if (selectedRows.Contains(rowIdentifier)) continue;//if you want to keep looping, otherwise break;
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use the Tag property of the DataGridViewRow to identify rows already selected.

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow r in dataGridView1.SelectedRows)
  if (r.Tag!=null) { Counter.Text=int.Parse(Counter.Text)+1 ; r.Tag=True ; }
```

Comment: I got error msg - Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'string'

Comment: ToString is missing : (int.Parse(Counter.Text)+1).ToString()

Comment: Again want to clear the scenario - I have a button which when I click updates the counter. The logic should be that the counter should not be updates if the same row is selected by the user by chance. Is it a good idea to create a new db to check uniqueness of the row selected since I the logic is would be in the button_click event?

Answer (score 0):

I would add a condition statement that checks to see if the variable is dirty or has already been updated.  This sounds similar to a concurrency issue or checking concurrency, I'm sure if you searched for ways to resolve concurrency issues the logic used would be similar.  I agree with @johnc

I would utilize the onclick event then disable the ability to click the same row again.

OR use some other unique property of the row and check against it.

```
if(row.uniqueProperty == -1)
{

    Counter.Text = Convert.ToString(i + 1);
}
```

Comment: sorry if this is confusing, just learnt C# this last year, I'm more of a chef just starting to love2code